# Selected text color in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to set the selected text color for control like TextBox, ComboBox simply or do I have to setup a style trigger to change the selected text background.

I have a set of styles applied to the controls, but one of the things that isn't styled is the selected text, it's defaulted to a pale blue. I've tried setting some of the properties of the `SystemColors` class but this had no affect.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"
                 Color="Red" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}"
                 Color="Red" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                 Color="Orange" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}"
                 Color="Orange" />
```

Comment: Hello @AwkwardCoder. Did you find a better solution to override the highlight color?

Comment: I didn't, the only way I know of is override the template / style for the control, extracting the style using something like MS Blend and then modifying accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [TextBoxBase.SelectionBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.selectionbrush.aspx) property

Comment: This works for the majority but not all the instances, accepting it as the answer for now :)

Comment: @AwkwardCoder Which instance is giving you troubles? Even ComboBox has a TextBox in it. Could just set it to the TargetType globally via Setters.

Comment: I set the implicit template value but it's not being picked up by comboboxes - the template has been overridden, i need to investigate further

Comment: Well, there's practically always a way if you want to share some specifics or maybe a separate question.